# Verify if a sql query returns any row in a .sh file

Tags: shell

I'm new in shell programming.

I've to verify if certain sql query returns any tuple/row.

If something`s returned then one action is made, else another action is made. Something like this:

```
 getResults(){
    getAnyResults=`sqlplus -s $MMUSER/$MMPASS <<!
    set verify off
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    set pages 0
    set pause off
    set linesize 2500
    
    select x, y, z
    from A;

    exit;
    !`
 }
```

**Edit 02/09/2021 - Begin**

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    x INTEGER,
    y INTEGER,
    z INTEGER
);

SELECT * FROM A;
```

The above code should not return any tuple since i've not inserted anything in table A

However if i do this:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    x INTEGER,
    y INTEGER,
    z INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO A 
VALUES(1,2,3);
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM A;
```

one tuple must be returned(1,2,3)

What i want is to verify if any tuple is returned and if so action1 is made, if any tuple is not returned, action2 is made

**Edit 02/09/2021 - End**

I'm storing the query's result on **getAnyResults** variable.

If variable **getAnyResults** returns any tuple/row one action is made, else another action is made

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you put an example of output and detail a bit more what you want to check?

Comment: Check the new edit, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getAnyResults` must contain at least a tuple, you can just check this way:

```
if echo "$getAnyResults" | grep -Eq "\(.+\)"; then
   echo ACTION1
else
   echo ACTION2
fi
```

Of course the regexp can be more strict if you need this.

According to the comments, you need to match something like `x=1, y=2, z=3` or `x=5, y=8, z=4`. In this case a suitable test is:

```
echo "$getAnyResults" | grep -Eq "x=[0-9]+, y=[0-9]+, z=[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Can you please explain me " | grep -Eq "\(.*\)" " ? Why does this mean the query returns any tuple?

Comment: Matches all strings containing `(`, any sequence of characters, `)`. `q` is for quiet, so the matching string, if any, is not printed in the output.

Comment: And " -Eq " it's equals, right? 

Just a last question, probably a stupid one, but, does this solution guarantees me that only tuples/rows are returned by my query? For example, if any error is returned by the query, ACTION1 will be made?

Comment: I ask this because ACTION1 can only be made if valid tuples/rows are returned.

Comment: No, just that in the variable you'll find a `(` followed by some chars, and a `)`.
If you have more informations about the content of the tuple, a better regexp can be used.

Comment: Ok, but this is not precisely what i want. I only want ACTION1 to be made if a valid tuple is found. For example in this case x=1, y=2, z=3 or x=5, y=8, z=4

Comment: In this case you can use: `grep -Eq "x=[0-9]+, y=[0-9]+, z=[0-9]+"`

Comment: Ok, this last solution seems more reliable to me

Comment: Can you post this last solution in your answer to mark it as correct?

Comment: Just one last thing. In my specific case(not the one i've posted it) the datatype of x is VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), y is NUMBER(2,0) and z is VARCHAR2(10 BYTE). In this case, the solution is: grep -Eq "x="\(.*\)", y=[0-9]+, z="\(.*\)"; ?

Comment: Should be I think `grep -Eq 'x=".+", y=[0-9]+, z=".+"'`.